# no application icons (quicksynergy or florence) in "Indicator Applet Complete"

Tags: 11.04, applet, notification-area, indicator

i'm running ubuntu 11.04 classic.

in previous versions of ubuntu i had florence or quick energy staying in the indicator applet after i close or minimmize them. but now only drop box shows up.

as a result, when i minimize florence, it runs in the background but there is no way to open it since there is no icon in the applet.

not sure how to even approach the problem. i hope i don't have to reinstal the system to find out which application broke the icons.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can whitelist all icons in tray, with

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

It does not work for all apps, for example for KeePassX that I use. In such a case you can configure the app to not use the system tray.